# How to recover contents of .tex file from auxiliary files?

Tags: data-recovery, latex

I was writing a  document in LaTeX. I saved it and generated a .pdf file from it. But then suddenly my PC crashed. When I opened the .tex file again it was blank.

Is there any way to regenerate the contents of .tex file from .aux, .log, .synctex.gz files?

Comment: Can't help in this case. But for the next time try something lik this (it's free): http://www.alexosoft.de/de/produkte/backup-service-home/uebersicht.aspx

Comment: Given that tex files are just super small plaintext files you were saving it in Dropbox, right?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to regenerate the contents of .tex file from .aux, .log, .synctex.gz files?

No.

`.aux` files just contain information for cross-referencing inside the document. `.log` contains the log from compiling. `.synctex.gz` files allow you to locate document positions from a document viewer.

You have to restore your document from a backup, or “back-port” it from the generated PDF.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe helpful for you. I suffered also on this problem. I solved this by open the null tex file in the text editor (winedt) and right click on the file on the top bar. Then choose 'open backup'.

Best wish

Answer (score 0):

Commiserations. I had a similar problem. I used the following workflow which might help anyone else in a similar situation.

TexStudio froze and crashed while I was editing my book. Although I didn't knowingly hit 'Save' at any stage, unfortunately, the crash resulted in TexStudio saving a blank .tex file over the original source .tex file without asking for confirmation. My .tex files automatically sync with Dropbox, so my cloud backup was also destroyed, along with months of work...

I had compiled a .pdf during the session a few minutes previously, however, so there was a recent record of my work, but it was no longer in a format which could be edited further in TexStudio, or any other tex editor.

Unlike MS Word, TeXstudio does not save versions of the current .tex file as temporary or backup files at hidden / system locations, so restoring from these was not an option.

Fortunately I'd done a complete back up of my HDD to an external HDD a few days previously using DejaDup, so was able to use this to retrieve an older version of the source .tex file which contained most of my work, along with the corresponding .pdf output.
DejaDup can restore all files from a backup, but can also restore individual files which can be selected by opening Nautilus browser (enter 'nautilus' at the command line to run it if Nautilus is not your distro's default browser), right clicking on the file names and selecting 'Revert To Previous Version' from the drop-down menu.

I then needed to find the changes made since the external HDD backup, and update the restored .tex file with these. To do this, I converted both .pdf files into raw text files using the utility pdftotext (which came already included in my Ubuntu install) using the command line: pdftotext input.pdf output.txt

I then used a visual difference tool (Meld) to open both converted text files side-by-side to see where changes had been made between my previous external HDD backup and the crash; and cut and pasted the sections of changed text into my restored .tex file. The whole process took several hours, but I recovered all of my work.

TeXstudio has an autosave command which is disabled by default under: Options>Configure TeXstudio>Advanced Options>Special Options>AutoSave All Files. Autosaves can be set to occur at regular timed intervals from every 5 to 60 min. However this is not without its risks, and I don't think this would have helped in my case as my source .tex file was overwritten automatically and TeXstudio does not seem to allow the option to autosave a backup version of the current .tex file with a different name or to a different location.

Moral of the story: Compile your .tex files to .pdf frequently as you work, and don't rely on syncing to cloud-based servers as your only backup: do full and frequent backups to an external HDD too.